# Add new Row to bottom of table and copy all formulas from the row above is not working

Tags: excel, vba

I have a number of named tables on different named sheets which I update daily.  I'd love to be able to run VBA code that would add a row to the bottom of each table and copy the formulas from the row above to that new row.

I have that almost working on a single named table on a named sheet with the following:

```
'Add New Row to Table
Sub Add_Row_to_Table()
    
    'Declare Variables
    Dim oSheetName As Worksheet
    Dim sTableName As String
    Dim loTable As ListObject
    
    'Define Variable
    sTableName = "World"
    
    'Define WorkSheet object
    Set oSheetName = Sheets("Global_Chart")
    
    'Define Table Object
    Set loTable = oSheetName.ListObjects(sTableName)
    
    'Add New row to the table
    loTable.ListRows.Add
       
End Sub
```

However, only five of the seven cells in the row copy down the formula from the cell above it.  Here are the formulas:

```
Column A is     =A210+1
Column B is     =OFFSET(Global_Cases!$D$270, 0, ROW()-1, 1, 1)
Column C is     =B211-B210
Column D is     =SUM(C198:C211)/14
Column E is     =OFFSET(Global_Deaths!$D$270, 0, ROW()-1, 1, 1)
Column F is     =E211-E210
Column G is     =SUM(F198:F211)/14
```

NOTE: Only the first table on each sheet actually use the letters 'A' through 'G' so a more correct statement would be the first column in the table, the second column in the table, etc.

All the columns copy the respective formulas down except Column D and Column G and I cannot find any good explanation for why that is.

I need to try and get this working on a single table before I add any nesting loops to cycle through all tables on all sheets.

I'd be happy to share the Spreadsheet, but it's huge.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you have only discovered the tip of the iceberg so far. The `ListRows.Add` method has an optional property called `AlwaysInsert`. Since you don't specify it its value will be *False* in your code. Here is the explanation from MSDN.
*"If False, if the row below the table is empty, the table will expand to occupy that row without shifting cells below it, but if the row below the table contains data, those cells will be shifted down when the new row is inserted."*

Now, your worksheet seems to have a lot of data below the table. Perhaps row 198 will be replaced by the newly inserted row, causing the formulas that refer to it not to be copied. If this doesn't happen right away, it's likely to happen sooner or later as you keep adding rows.

Another thing you should be aware of is that a *ListRow* has has many cells as the table has columns. Adding such a row inserts cells, not sheet rows. Therefore, if your data below the table are wider than the table, adding a ListRow will shift only the cells below the table down (provided *AlwaysInsert* is True), leaving other cells in place. Therefore *AlwaysInsert* doesn't come without its own disadvantages.

The sword that cuts through the knot is not to have data below the table. And that would most probably solve the problem you are asking about.

BTW, the first cell of a table is `ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 1)`, irrespective of the sheet row and sheet column that location might be at.

Comment: So first, there is no data below any tables.  I have one table in one sheet, and then five tables in another but they are laid out from left to right, not top to bottom.

The other thing I discovered after posting this message is that if I manually right click in the last Row of a table and select Insert Row Below which is presumably more or less what is done with the ListRows.Add method the new data, even if I copy all the formulas from the row above the new table row to the new table row, that the data does NOT get picked up by the Chart that feeds off the table.

(Continued)

Comment: (Continuation)

However, if I put the cursor in the last Row of the table, right click and then Select Add Row Above and then go to the row above the newly added row and copy that row's formulas to the now next two rows (the last two rows) that the Chart will pick up the addition of the new row of data.

So maybe I needed to state that to begin with.

Fundamentally all of the tables pick up their data from source data in other sheets in the Workbook.  That raw data I download on a daily basis and then add a new column (each column represents a single day's data) with it.

(Continued)

Comment: (Continuation)

Once that is done, I then go to the sheets where the tables are, add a new row above the last row of each table, then copy the row above that new row down to the last two rows - once I do that for each table, each of the six charts are now updated with no further ado.

I'd like to automate the steps performed in the paragraph above - already have VBA that exports all the charts in the workbook as images and adding this new functionality to that vba would further reduce my daily workload by about half.

Comment: All your formula except B and E refer to cells on the same sheet as the table. Therefore they may be affected by the added row. The way you describe your setup the formulas can't return correct results. Bear in mind that relative references will update (change the referenced row address) when copied to another row. I feel that using tables at all may not be the best solution for you. Consider using named ranges instead.

Comment: If data within the table are omitted from the chart you haven't linked the table column to the chart. The behaviour you describe is typical for when named ranges are referenced. They expand only when a row is added within them but not when added below or above. In your setup the only argument in favour of using tables at all is the ability to reference table columns which expand regardless of where you add the row. Hence my question what benefit tables are to you.

Answer (score 0):

Variatus:

I don't think you get how the table is set up.  This table is several hundred rows deep at this point, the two formulas you say can't return correct results merely adds up the total of the current and previous 13 rows of data that exists in that same table for a 14 day average.  Adding a row below the last row of the table, then copying the formulas from what is now the second from last row works just peachy UNLESS the row gets added via VBA.

However, I took the script kiddie way out and simply recorded a macro that works just peachy for me.  Thanks.